# Can't import Maven dependencies/jars (file permission issue)

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu, file-permissions

I copied the .m2 folder in my home directory from my backup.
when I import the project in intellij idea and try to run it, all maven imports show: `Cannot resolve symbol "***"`.

Then I found that there was a permission problem in .m2 folder.
I set its permissions after some research:
All directory has permission : `drwxrwxr-x` (775)
All files has permission :  `rw-rw-r` (664)

But after these changes it still wasn't working. So I set all file's permission to `rwxrwxrwx` (777) (Only for testing) but still it's not working.

[image]

So what permission should I set to `~/.m2` file and folder for working perfect.

I'm thankful for your answer and explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the owner ~/.m2 is the actual user who uses the IDE. Try to change it and see if that works.

Comment: Also try Invalidate caches.

Comment: @RakeshS Yes user is correct. and I also try and set it again but still its not working.

Comment: @talex Thanks but I already tried it :)